# What can I do about this outlet nut?

Tags: receptacle

[image]

There's a nut that holds the electrical box in at the bottom right. When I screw in the outlet, that nut blocks it from going all the way in. It's also making it difficult to put a cover on.

What could I do with the nut to solve this? I'm thinking I could relocate it but I'm not sure where I could relocate it to.

Comment: Take it out and replace it with a screw with a flatter head. And while you're about it add some more screws to hold the box more securely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower right hand "ear" on the receptacle can be broken off. It is scored for just that purpose. You bend it back and forth with pliers and it breaks off. The screw will then not prevent the receptacle from fitting flush. If the screw nevertheless interferes with the cover plate fitting flush, you could replace the screw with one which has a lower head.

In fact all 4 of the ears could be removed and the receptacle screwed hard to the metal box. Some sources say that the purpose of those ears is to provide spacer washers in case the box is too far into the wall. So if you want try one or two of them between each mounting tab and the metal box, you could. But this box would appear to be in the plane of the wall and you would save them for later use.

http://www.diychatroom.com/f18/receptacles-mounting-ears-what-purpose-4959/

Comment: Given that this is a metal box and the ground wire is clipped to the box on the same side as the hot terminal on the receptacle it would be prudent to wrap insulating electrical tape (several turns) around the receptacle to cover the screw terminals.

Comment: The purpose of the ears is to hold it flush against drywall or other surface if it is high compared to the electrical box -- which happens a lot.  In that case, since the screws do not clamp the metal yoke of the receptacle hard against the box, you cannot rely on the metal box-yoke connection for grounding, and must hardwire a ground.  Likewise here due to that odd bit of insulating paper.

Comment: @Harper, the odd bit of insulating paper is just to keep the screw from falling off. The head of the screw is in electrical contact with the metal tab on the receptacle and is in contact with the box via the threads. But some better quality receptacles have a paper keeper on one end but a metal wire keeper on the other. With this device one could start the screws and tear off the paper on one end, say the bottom screw. The best practice would be to detach all 4 ears and have the receptacle firmly  attached to the box mechanically and electrically.

Comment: Nope, code does not permit grounding via screw heads or threads. Considering the surface contact area I am not surprised.

Comment: So if you don't have a ground wire to the receptacle and the box is back into the wall at all, then you would have to **break off all 4 ears and tear off the paper so the tab of the receptacle would make contact over a broad area**. If the box was back a little, you would use the 4 ears as conducting spacers between the receptacle and the box?

Comment: If the box is back, then you wouldn't attempt a contact ground, you'd let the ears do their job, let the receptacle float away from the box,  and jumper a ground.  This is the common method where drywall is involved.  The thing where you rely on the hard steel-on-steel connection mainly shows up in industrial where you have conduit and bare boxes on walls. It's a lot easier there.

Comment: @Harper suppose that in the present case that the wiring is unarmored NM (or the armored version) going to this metal box. There is a ground wire clipped to the box. The easiest thing to do would be to remove the ears and screw the receptacle firmly to the box, after cleaning off the flat on the box. So are you saying this is unacceptable and that one must connect a ground wire to the receptacle?

Comment: @Harper so would you unclip the ground from the box, put on a pigtail with a wire nut (since the ground wire is too short) and attach the pigtail to the ground screw of the  receptacle?